# Unix MicroFocus COBOL TRACE

Tags: unix, trace, cobol

Any one knows how to turn on the trace in Unix Micro Focus Cobol?
I googled it. I need to put READY TRACE statement, but in addition, it also said something about Compiler directive which I do not know.
My compiling statement is like this:
cob -xvP /src/AAA.CBL /obj/TORDCNCL.int -o /bin/AAA
There is no man page for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current [MF documentation on the `READY TRACE` statement](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/vc50pu6/DevHub/HRLHLHDEBU08.html):

- you have to use another dialect than `VSC2` (where it is documentary only)
- it is likely only accepted + handled in `OSVS` dialect at all
- it needs the [`TRACE` directive](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/vc50pu6/DevHub/HRHTRHEHTM0D.html) to be active, by either

  - [passing syntax-check phase directive to the compiler](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/vc50pu6/DevHub/BKCYCYFLAGS001F003.html) via (in this case)  `-C TRACE` or
  - the option to only activate it for this single program is to add the directive directly in the source (as it is "initial" you need to place it before any program code), to do so put the following in your program:

```
       $SET TRACE
```